# Program execution stops when run in background

Tags: c, exec, fork, background-process

I have a simple C program which runs an application ("flute-static") twice (with the help of for loop) using fork() and execl(). The application itself is interactive i.e., it uses the shell to take inputs from user and to print outputs. If I run the program normally no problem occurs. But when I run the C program from background, the main program stops. Here is the program.

```
int main()
{
    int i, pid;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1)
        {
            printf("\nerror, failed to fork()");
        }
        else if (pid > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            /*we are the child*/
            execl("./flute-static", "./flute-static", "-send", "-a192.168.190.1", "/", "6666", "JFlute.1.2.tar.gz", NULL);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    while(1)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And output of running the program is this:

```
[root@localhost Flute]# ./a.out&
[3] 2643
[root@localhost Flute]#

[3]+  Stopped                 ./a.out
```

Why is this happening? And how can I solve the problem? Please help.

Comment: Are you getting any input to program from shell?

Comment: When I run the solo application in shell, it starts automatically and blocks the shell. It requires to press 'q' button to stop its execution. Since I don't want to stop it, I am not giving any inputs to the program from shell.

Comment: `runs an application ("flute-static") twice` -- is it? I think it's `path` and `arg(0)`, isn't it?

Comment: I run it twice using a for loop.

Comment: What the `flute-static` file is doing, whether it is passing any signal to parent like sigstop.

Comment: That I don't know. Is there any way to know that?

Comment: Run you program like `strace ./a.out &` and check the highlighted lines are printing before program terminates.  `--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGTTIN (Stopped (tty input)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---`

Comment: Thanks. Last three lines are: clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fb27b6cca10) = 22202
--- SIGTTOU {si_signo=SIGTTOU, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---